# Extract substring in bash from a file with pattern location from a given position to a special character

Tags: bash, http, curl, header, substring

I need to get a nonce from a http service
I am using curl and later openssl to calculate the sha1 of that nonce.
but for that i need to get the nonce to a variable

1 step (done)

```
curl --user username:password -v -i -X POST http://192.168.0.202:8080/RPC3 -o output.txt -d @initial.txt
```

and now, the output file @output.txt holds the http reponse

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: WinREST HTTP Server/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 89
WWW-Authenticate: ServiceAuth realm="WinREST", nonce="/wcUEQOqUEoS64zKDHEUgg=="

<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body>Error 401: Unauthorized</body></html>
```

I have to get the position of "nonce=" and extract all the way to the " char.
How can I get in bash, the value of nonce ??

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple with `grep` using the `-o`/`--only-matching` and `-P`/`--perl-regexp` options (available in GNU `grep`):

```
$ grep -oP 'nonce="\K[^"]+' output.txt
/wcUEQOqUEoS64zKDHEUgg==
```

The `-o` option will print only matched part, which would normally include `nonce="` if we had not used the [reset match start](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#resetmatchstart) escape sequence available in PCRE.

Additionally, if your `output.txt` (i.e. server response) can contain *more than one* nonce, and you are interested in only reading the first one, you can use the `-m1` option (as Glenn suggests):

```
$ grep -oPm1 'nonce="\K[^"]+' output.txt
```

---

To store that nonce in a variable, simply use command substitution; or just pass it through `openssl sha1` to get that digest you need:

```
$ nonce=$(grep -oPm1 'nonce="\K[^"]+' output.txt)
$ echo "$nonce"
/wcUEQOqUEoS64zKDHEUgg==

$ read hash _ <<<"$(grep -oPm1 'nonce="\K[^"]+' output.txt | openssl sha1 -r)"
$ echo "$hash"
2277ef32822c37b5c2b1018954f750163148edea
```

Comment: Could also add the `-m1` option to quit after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU sed for this as below :

```
ubuntu$ cat output.txt
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: WinREST HTTP Server/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 89
WWW-Authenticate: ServiceAuth realm="WinREST", nonce="/wcUEQOqUEoS64zKDHEUgg=="

<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body>Error 401: Unauthorized</body></html>

ubuntu$ sed -E -n  's/(.*)(nonce="\/)([a-zA-Z0-9=]+)(")(.*)/\3/gp' output.txt
wcUEQOqUEoS64zKDHEUgg==
```

Regards!

Comment: A couple of notes: i) You seem to be missing the leading slash from the nonce value -- your character set is too restrictive; ii) you don't need to capture *everything*, only the stuff you need in the replacement: `s/.*nonce="([^"]+)".*/\1/p`

Comment: @glennjackman Nice. thank for the advises buddy. I seriously never thought of capturing only the group I wanted to extract. And yes. I misplaced the slash. :O